# ReactJS Express server side not receive main route

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using ReactJS with Express JS to develop a website.
I faced a problem when I open the main domain `/` (`https://www.example.com`) in the browser, there are no any routes are executed in my server side even `app.get("*")` not executed and so I can not control the main route redirection.

My server side code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(express.json({type: ['application/json', 'text/plain']}))
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(session({secret: 'xxxxxxx', cookie: {maxAge: 1576800000000}, resave: true, saveUninitialized: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// not work
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send("");
})

// work for all routes except "/"
app.get("*", async (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send("");
})

const port = 3011;
app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

Comment: what status code do you get instead?

Comment: I didn't get any status code; The problem there is any route is executed and blank page on the browser

Answer (score 0):

OK, what do you expect to see?
Here:

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send("");
```

you tell to send nothing into the browser except code 404. So that's why the page is blank. But it works. To see the result you can open up the developer tools in your browser and check "network" tab - it shows all the responses from the server and you can easily find your 404 answer.
Replace 404 in your code with any other status to see how it works (do not forget to restart server when updates are done).
You can also put something but empty string as send argument, like this:

```
res.status(404).send('Hello')
```

As the result you will find "Hello" on the page, and 404 response in developer console tools.

Pay attention that it is not enough just to send 404 status to browser. You are building API, so data can be requested by browsers, applications etc. So you decide how to handle all these options.

For example, you can make a "404.html" page in the root directory and replace you code with this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // respond with html page
  res.status(404).sendFile("404.html", { root: __dirname });
})
```

On that case, custom error page will be sent to the browser.

Comment: As my question, i can handle any log or debug to know if the route is executed, BUT the route is never executed, I mean the code never reach `res.status` but if i put `app.get("/test")` and then i navigate to `domain/test` the route is executed

Comment: John, sorry for that misunderstanding. That's because you code seems to be correct. I checked your code several times and could not find any problems. The same code (with no USEs section) works perfectly - there is nothing to break, actually. Have no idea what could go wrong then.

Comment: I Found the problem is here: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));` without this line the route works find BUT without it the react engine can not access any `js` file